# Sorting alphabetically on select in rails using formtastic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting

I have bunch of states I need to sort alphabetically in rails using formtastic. There is one small caveat. In the states table, I have a name for the state with 'N/A'. The 'N/A' has to come first the collection of all states using select form helper method. This is my code currently:

```
f.input :state, :as => :select, :collection => State.all,  :include _blank => false
```

How do I place the 'N/A' state name at the top of collection followed by the rest of states alphabetically? Example: 'N/A, Alabama, Alaska, etc....'.

Thanks to everyone for help/clues.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
f.input :state, 
        :as => :select, 
        :collection => State.all.sort_by(&:name), 
        :prompt => 'N/A'
```

Using `State.all.sort_by(&:name)` to sort by the state name attribute, and using `prompt: 'N/A'` to show `N/A` as the first option in the `select`.

or, sort in the db using:

```
f.input :state, 
        :as => :select, 
        :collection => State.order(:name), 
        :prompt => 'N/A'
```

Comment: Thanks. However, even with prompt the 'N/A' keeps showing in the middle of the collection.

Comment: That's possible only if you have state with name `N/A`.  If you want to filter out those `N/A` in database table then you can replace `State.all.sort_by(&:name)` with `State.where("name <> 'N/A'").order(:name)`

Comment: Is there a way to force prompt? I am still getting 'N/A' in the middle of the collection.

Comment: @NicholasAlek, I am not sure now to help you debug this, it's very likely a data issue.  Can you check to make sure that the query `State.where("name <> 'N/A'").order(:name)` returns what you expect in the `rails console`? Another thing to check is, is `N/A` used in database or is it overridden somewhere?

Comment: Thanks vee. How stupid of me, I forgot to mention, this a Rails 2.3 app, sadly.

Comment: So, the 'N/A' is in the database. If I do something like, State.all(:conditions => ["name <> 'N/A'], :order => :name), using Rails 2.3 syntax, I get the correct order of all states, but the 'N/A' is gone, even with the prompt set to 'N/A'. Any thoughts?

Comment: @NicholasAlek, unfortunately I cannot test this at the moment.  Please see [`select`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select#271-Prompt-vs-Select) on the API dock.  The linked comment should have your solution.